# Calcular dias entre duas datas

Tags: php

Pessoal tenho o seguinte código

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['data']));
                $data_preset = date('Y/m/d');
                $diferenca = strtotime($data_preset) - strtotime($row['data']);
                $dias = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24)); 

        echo '<p style="color:#6a727a;">Data do pedido(a):</p><p class="color">'. $row['data'] .'</p></div></div><br>';
        if($dias<=15){
            echo '<p class="actived">Pedido feito a '. $dias .' dias, está dentro do prazo </p></br>';
      
        }else{
            echo '<p class="foraD">Pedido feito a '. $dias .' dias, está fora do prazo, por favor verificar  </p></br>';
        
        }
```

ele funciona bem porém eu cadastrei um pedido para teste no dia 2020-09-10
era para acusar que faz 17 dias que o pedido foi feito porem está acusando que faz 18 dias

eu também cadastrei um pedido teste feito hoje 27/09/2020 e está acusando que já faz 1 dia que o pedido foi feito e não 0 dias

o $row['data'] é o while que recuperar a data.
e estou fazendo essa postagem as 21:14 do dia 27/09/2020

Comment: Se é um padrão que está respondendo o cálculo com 1 dia a mais que o esperado em todas as situações, por quê não ajusta o código com `-1`? 

`$dias = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24)) - 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bom dia amigo, como vai?

eu fiz no meu da seguinte forma, (não leve em conta se estiver bagunçado, pois sou uma pessoa que está apenas criando o próprio site em forma de sistema, para meus colaboradores usarem, enfim esta aqui

```
$hoje = date('Y-m-d');
$venc = $mostrar[3]; // já vem formatado em 'Y-m-d'

// converte as datas para o formato timestamp
 $d1 = strtotime($hoje); 
 $d2 = strtotime($venc);

// verifica a diferença em segundos entre as duas datas e divide pelo número de segundos que um dia possui - resumindo, da o resultado em dias (multipliquei por *-1 porque esta retornando um valor negativo, exemplo -4dias, multiplicando *-1 remove o '-'

$dias = (($d2 - $d1)/86400)*-1;
```

Comment: estive pensando, pode ser facil de resolver também, crie uma formatação antes de carregar as datas, da seguinte forma date('Y-m-d') o que pode estar acontecendo com seu código, é estar somando junto as horas em que foi salvo, dando um valor picado e quando sendo maior que ,5 esta arredondando para maior e vice versa, tente mudar também o formato da datapreset, está de uma maneira que o strtotime não reconheça

Comment: eu fiz do jeito que você falou porem não funcionou, oque funciono foi o seu código de cima, e no meu para arruma eu descobri que era só adicionar date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');me ajudou muito xD